# Script will run in root terminal but not when run as a cronjob as a user

Tags: terminal, cron

The cron job:

```
51 18 * * * /home/XXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/wpai_scripts/ld_wpai_script 2>> /home/XXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/wpai_scripts/ld_wpai_script_cron.log
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

cd /home/XXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/ && wget "https://XXXXXXsystems.com.au/WSDataFeed.asmx/DownLoad?CustomerCode=XXXXXX&WithHeading=true&WithLongDescription=true&DataType=0" -O leader-direct.zip && rm -rf ld-direct/ ; mkdir ld-direct/ && unzip -q leader-direct.zip -d ld-direct/ && rm -f leader-direct.zip && mv -f ld-direct/*.csv lead.csv && rm -rf ld-direct/ && wget -q -O - "https://www.XXXXXX.com.au/wp-load.php?import_key=XXXXXX&import_id=28&action=trigger"
```

My scripts will run when executed in root terminal but not when run as a cronjob as a user.

The crob job does fire, as `grep XXXXXX /var/log/cron` gives:

```
Jan 15 18:38:01 server CROND[32025]: (XXXXXX) CMD (/home/XXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/wpai_scripts/ld_wpai_script 2>> /home/XXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/wpai_scripts/ld_wpai_script_cron.log)
```

What I have tried:

1. The permission of the script is ensured to be `755`.
2. I have tried matching the env `PATH="/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/root/bin"` for my root and user in the user crontab file and since the cron job can be executed unproblematically in
   root terminal, then I figured that rules out PATH being the problem.
3. Ensuring there is a linebreak (empty line) at the end of the crontab file.
4. Using the full path of commands, e.g. `user/bin/wget`

My research has shown these are the 4 most common causes that thwart people running cron jobs.  Yet I think I've ruled them out.

So what could be wrong?

Comment: Is the script accessible as a user? (i.e. all the containing directories need search permission)  What output was mailed to the user?  (BTW, you might want `set -e` instead of a long chain of `&&`, and please add some newlines!)

Comment: And did you try executing the commend from the crontab in a plain (`sh`) shell running as the target user, with a cron-like environment?

Comment: Does wget for that URL need a proxy variable?

Comment: Re: `And did you try executing the commend from the crontab in a plain (sh) shell running as the target user, with a cron-like environment?` I'm sorry, can you please be more explicit; what would you suggest I try in explicit steps?

Comment: Re: `Does wget for that URL need a proxy variable?` Forgive me, I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: If I try manually executing the script in user terminal, I get `-bash: /home/XXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/wpai_scripts/sy_wpai_script_cron.log: Permission denied`.  But the script has permission `755` set?

Comment: That seems to say that your user is missing write permissions on the folder you are trying to output your log to.

Comment: I notice that your PATH does not include `/bin` or `/sbin` I would expect these to be needed (they certainly are for Debian distros)

Comment: @gogoud I'm using Centos 7.  Does your advice still apply?

Comment: @fra-san I've set all files and folders concerned to permissions `777`.  Still get the error associated with `cp: cannot create regular file ‘XXXXX.txt’: Permission denied`

Comment: Lol ... for sur you must include /bin and /sbin ... where is located `mkdir` command on your system ? I would bet on /bin ...

Comment: @binarym you mean like this: `PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/root/bin"`?

Comment: That error message is from `cp`, but there is no `cp` in the script you posted. Are you saying that, despite having changed the permissions of your directories, you are manually copying a file with `cp` and getting that error?

Comment: Also, those look like the paths of an Apache/Wordpress instance. I'm no expert, but I seem to recall that they are on purpose only accessible to a specific user; fiddling with permissions may be by design supposed to break something. You may want to find a more proper way to upload a file to that  web server (e.g. copy it as root and then adjust ownership and permissions).

Comment: About `PATH`: CentOS 7 is based on RHEL 7, whose file system hierarchy has `/bin` and `/sbin` [merged into](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-file_system_layout) `/usr`. While corner cases of applications that misbehave if `/bin` is not in `PATH` cannot be ruled out, this is unlikely to be an issue in the context of your question.